# JFreechart Gantt chart millisecond X axis?

Tags: jfreechart

I am using JFreechart to create a Gantt chart, however the Date (X-axis) is being displayed in the Date format HH:MM:SS.

Is there any way to get this x-axis to only display milliseconds? Since this is a Gantt chart my x-axis values are of type SimpleTimePeriod which I constructed with milliseconds.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ChartFactory.createGanttChart()`, you can specify any desired format when calling `setNumberFormatOverride()` on the plot's `DateAxis`. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513).

Comment: I believe it is a CategoryAxis and not a DateAxis.

Comment: One of each: [`createGanttChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1303).

Comment: Oh yes of course you are right! I will look into this further, but it seems that there aren't any built-in formats for displaying the time in milliseconds. So I guess I should extend NumberFormat with a custom class?

Comment: You're welcome; you may have already found `SimpleDateFormat` and `SSS`.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot(); 
DateAxis range = new DateAxis("Date");
range.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("ss.SSS"));
plot.setRangeAxis(range);
```