# JavaFX real-time LineChart with time axis

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, javafx-2

I'm trying to plot real-time graph, with time axis, but I have found the `LineChart` constructor only has the signature.

```
LineChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis)
```

I think embedding jfree chart in javafx is not a proper solution.

I want a few of the jfree features in a javafx `LineChart`, is this possible?

Comment: Fantastic question! Useful answer! Terrible Moderators!  Why close perfectly good questions with valid answers?  I'm just glad closed questions still come up in searches.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Download Ensemble sample from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html

There are several examples in it for dynamic charts, e.g. "Advanced Stock Line Chart". You can take a look at their source code directly in the application.

[image]

To show time on axis you can use string and DateFormatter:

```
    BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());

    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    chart.getData().addAll(series1);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + i * 11111);
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(dateFormat.format(date), Math.random() * 500));
    }
```

Comment: Yes this code is fine but the problem is I want to show the real time instead of incremented values in time axis!!!

Comment: exactly ... that's what i want

Comment: how can we set Range for time here? I mean, i only want last ten minutes. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The problem is, that you have to fill missing categories for time where you have no value. Otherwise you may have categories like this: 4:00, 11:00, 12:00 and they are placed in same distances from each other. JavaFx chart really sucks without time series support.

Answer (score 0):

The class [`org.jfree.chart.demo.TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html) is included with the distribution. It is pictured in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), and its [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html#line.70) illustrates the use of the factory method `ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()`. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513).

Comment: I think you're supposed to use `createTimeSeriesChart()`.

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee: [tag:jfreechart] works with [tag:javafx]; alter the model, e.g. `TimeSeries`, and the view will update itself.