# JavaFX - show graph in pane on checkbox click

Tags: javafx

I have FXML  file that has `Pane` as one of it's entries, used to show graph. It is not not visible by default. When checkbox is checked, the `Pane` is visible. Now I have to add graph in `Pane` and show graph  when pane is visible. How to achieve this? I have created graph using this link. [JavaFX real-time LineChart with time axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064406/javafx-real-time-linechart-with-time-axis)

Comment: Can you be more precise about what exact behavior you want? Do you want to add the graph only once when the pane becomes visible for the first time, or do you want to remove the graph when the pane is hidden and add again when the pane is shown again? Would it be the same graph, or a new graph on each show?

Comment: @TomasMikula I want to remove the graph when the pane is hidden and add again when the pane is shown again. Graph will be same means LineChart graph, only values will be dyanmic.(Value of Xaxis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pane.visibleProperty().addListener((obs, wasVisible, isVisible) -> {
    if(isVisible) { // pane became visible, add the graph
        LineChart<X, Y> chart = ...;
        pane.getChildren().add(chart);
    } else { // pane became hidden, remove the graph
        pane.getChildren().clear();
    }
});
```