# JFreeChart: How to auto adjust range axis min/max while panning (with fixed domain axis range)

Tags: jfreechart

I have a time series chart where domain range is auto-fixed, and due to this only part of large data-set is visible in the chart at a time. I have enabled only domain panning.

I am looking for a functionality such that when user pan in either direction, i.e. left or right, the range axis min/max values should adjust automatically as per the data visible in chart (and not as per complete data-set). Does JFreeChart-1.0.19 provide any such functionality out of the box?

On the other hand, I know that when dynamic data is added in time series (with fixed domain axis range), then setAutoAdjust on range axis will automatically adjust the min/max as per data visible on chart.

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217759/jfreechart-getting-the-min-and-max-of-the-current-displayed-dataset-for-auto-a).

Please find below the sample code: **TimeSeriesDemo.java**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Day;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class TimeSeriesDemo extends ApplicationFrame {
    public TimeSeriesDemo1(String title) {
        super(title);
        JPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "Nifty 50 Close",  // title
            "Date",             // x-axis label
            "Value",   // y-axis label
            dataset,            // data
            true,               // create legend?
            true,               // generate tooltips?
            false               // generate URLs?
        );

        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainPannable(true);
        plot.setRangePannable(false);

        XYItemRenderer r = plot.getRenderer();
        if (r instanceof XYLineAndShapeRenderer) {
            XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) r;
            renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(false);
        }

        DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        axis.setFixedAutoRange(6.0 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        return chart;
    }

    private static XYDataset createDataset() {
        TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Nifty 50");
        s1.add(new Day(11,1,2017),8380.65);
        s1.add(new Day(12,1,2017),8407.2);
        s1.add(new Day(13,1,2017),8400.35);
        s1.add(new Day(16,1,2017),8412.8);
        s1.add(new Day(17,1,2017),8398);
        s1.add(new Day(18,1,2017),8417);
        s1.add(new Day(19,1,2017),8435.1);
        s1.add(new Day(20,1,2017),8349.35);
        s1.add(new Day(23,1,2017),8391.5);
        s1.add(new Day(24,1,2017),8475.8);
        s1.add(new Day(25,1,2017),8602.75);
        s1.add(new Day(27,1,2017),8641.25);
        s1.add(new Day(30,1,2017),8632.75);
        s1.add(new Day(31,1,2017),8561.3);
        s1.add(new Day(1,2,2017),8716.4);
        s1.add(new Day(2,2,2017),8734.25);
        s1.add(new Day(3,2,2017),8740.95);
        s1.add(new Day(6,2,2017),8801.05);
        s1.add(new Day(7,2,2017),8768.3);
        s1.add(new Day(8,2,2017),8769.05);

        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(s1);

        return dataset;
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart);
        cp.setDomainZoomable(false);
        cp.setRangeZoomable(false);
        return cp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeSeriesDemo1 demo = new TimeSeriesDemo1("Time Series Demo 1");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe `SlidingXYDataset`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381430/230513).

Comment: Thank you @trashgod for sharing sliding dataset idea.I haven't explored the jFreeChart source code for panning, but do you think that by tweaking it somehow I can manage to set auto range on range-axis (y-axis). Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: As I recall, the patch included an example that may help guide you.

Comment: how to pan this demo?