# How to remove gaps between a time period of JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I was wondering how to remove times e.g. (5pm to 9am) from a time series in `JFreeChart`. I have tried this:

```
SegmentedTimeline baseTimeLine = new SegmentedTimeline(
    SegmentedTimeline.DAY_SEGMENT_SIZE,24,1);
```

However, I don't think this is what is needed to remove time periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SegmentedTimeline.newFifteenMinuteTimeline()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SegmentedTimeline.html#newFifteenMinuteTimeline--), seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/SegmentedTimeline.html#line.373), is a good example from which to start. In this example, `newWorkdayTimeline()` creates a new `SegmentedTimeline` that includes 8 hours and excludes 16 hours. It then starts on Monday after the prescribed number of hours have passed. It then chains a `newMondayThroughFridayTimeline()` to get weekdays, 9-5.

```
public static SegmentedTimeline newWorkdayTimeline() {
    SegmentedTimeline timeline = new SegmentedTimeline(
        SegmentedTimeline.HOUR_SEGMENT_SIZE, 8, 16);
    timeline.setStartTime(SegmentedTimeline.firstMondayAfter1900()
        + 8 * timeline.getSegmentSize());
    timeline.setBaseTimeline(SegmentedTimeline.newMondayThroughFridayTimeline());
    return timeline;
}
```

Starting form this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14198851/230513), I plotted a week of random hourly data. Zoom in on the domain axis to see the effect. I've included a continuous dataset to make it easier to see the segment borders.

```
private static final int N = 168; // a week
…
private static JFreeChart buildChart(
    …
    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    ((DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis()).setTimeline(newWorkdayTimeline());
    …
    return chart;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, how do i edit your code for as another example 10am to 4pm, i tried chaning the parameters to 6,18 and then + 6* however it just makes the x values and the domain not line up correctly

Comment: `6, 18` looks OK, but use `+ 9 *` to start at 10 AM.

Comment: Thanks you very much!