# Dynamically repaint ScatterPlot in jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, scatter-plot

I have a scatterplot which plots positions of agents. These positions change. I was wondering how can I repaint/redraw the scatterplot with the new positions

my drawing method. I need to redraw in the updatePositions function. Is there any way to implement any listener for ScatterPlot?

```
private ChartPanel createPanel() {
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            title, "", "", initPositions(),PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
    xyPlot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
    xyPlot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
    XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
    adjustAxis((NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis(), true);
    adjustAxis((NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis(), false);
    xyPlot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
}

private void adjustAxis(NumberAxis axis, boolean vertical) {
    axis.setRange(-1, lattice+1);
    axis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
    axis.setVerticalTickLabels(vertical);
}

private XYDataset initPositions() {
    XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection();

    for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++) {
        if(population.get(i).status==1){
            healthy.add(population.get(i).position[0], population.get(i).position[1]);
        }else if(population.get(i).status==2){
            infected.add(population.get(i).position[0], population.get(i).position[1]);
        }else if(population.get(i).status==3){
            recovered.add(population.get(i).position[0], population.get(i).position[1]);
        }
    }

    xySeriesCollection.addSeries(healthy);
    xySeriesCollection.addSeries(infected);
    xySeriesCollection.addSeries(recovered);
    return xySeriesCollection;
}

public void clear(){
    healthy.clear();
    infected.clear();
    recovered.clear();
}
public void updatePositions(ArrayList<Person> pop ){
    population = pop;

    for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++) {
        if(population.get(i).status==1){
            healthy.addOrUpdate(population.get(i).position[0], population.get(i).position[1]);
        }else if(population.get(i).status==2){
            infected.addOrUpdate(population.get(i).position[0], population.get(i).position[1]);
        }else if(population.get(i).status==3){
            recovered.addOrUpdate(population.get(i).position[0], population.get(i).position[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the method in the main class. The update of the positions is done at the "move" function

```
    public static void main(String [] args){
    createPopulation(populationSize);
    initInfection(infectRatio);

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {             
        @Override           
        public void run() {         
            DrawArea demo = new DrawArea("Demo", lattice, populationSize,population);               
            demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                
            demo.pack();                
            demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);               
            demo.setVisible(true);
            for(int i =0;i<1000;i++){

                for(int j=0; j<populationSize; j++){
                    population.get(j).move(0.8);
                }
                demo.clear();
                demo.updatePositions(population);
            }
        }          
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown below, the chart (view) listens to its dataset (model) and updates itself accordingly. When the <kbd>Move</kbd> button is pressed, each `XYDataItem` in the series in modified in `update()` to reflect its new position.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataItem;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19749344/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7208723/230513
 */
public class ScatterMove extends JFrame {

    private static final int N = 16;
    private static final String title = "Scatter Move Demo";
    private static final Random rand = new Random();
    private XYSeries moved = new XYSeries("Population");

    public ScatterMove(String s) {
        super(s);
        update();
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel control = new JPanel();
        control.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Move") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                moved.clear();
                update();
            }
        }));
        this.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void update() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            moved.add(new XYDataItem(rand.nextGaussian(), rand.nextGaussian()));
        }
    }

    private ChartPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            title, "X", "Y", createSampleData(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
        NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setRange(-3.0, 3.0);
        domain.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
        NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(-3.0, 3.0);
        range.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart){

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
    }

    private XYDataset createSampleData() {
        XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection();
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(moved);
        return xySeriesCollection;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScatterMove demo = new ScatterMove(title);
                demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                demo.pack();
                demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: well there goes my sleep xD. Thank you I will try it. It seems it will work with heavy modification(the points change in another class so I have to update/pass-to-the-plot-class the points everytime)

Comment: Instead of clearing and adding, you might want to look and extending an abstract class that implements `XYDataset`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513).