# Loading raw image file to Jfreechart and show result in a line graph

Tags: image, file, jfreechart

How can I read a raw image file and let it show as a line graph by using JFreechart?
For example, load the file via FileChooser and let it show as Line Graph. Graph with sample data and Button are already in place.

Comment: Why do you need `JFreeChart` to load an image?

Comment: it is not actually an image. It is a raw image file which is produced by an electronic device like a digitalcamera. The raw file contains coordinates for RGB layer from which any image format can be build. I was hoping that JFreechart would support showing this kind of format.

Answer (score 2):

`JFreeChart` has no direct support for [raw image format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format), but you can extend `AbstractXYDataset` to manage any data of interest. Examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459322/230513). An `XYDataset` can be used to create a variety of charts; see [`org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) for examples.