# Display an excel Page In java GUI

Tags: java, swing, excel, user-interface, applet

I need to display the entire Page of an Excel file in a Java GUI Application, I see that the POI Library May not help Much in this as I want spreadsheet view. What is the best way to do this in An Applet, swing, or a jSP Page? Any other Suggestions apart from Java Also welcome.

Comment: POI will help you in fetching the values. you can use this to display it in an html page using <table> tags

Comment: I need the Spreadsheet view because I Have graphs and Pie charts in the Excels

Comment: Use Extjs Grids and charts if you are unable to use POI api..

Comment: Apache poi will helpy you display a excel page in JFrame

Comment: @Raghunandan Even if it has Graph? How DO i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage an existing Excel installation by using the `Desktop` method [`open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29), which "Launches the associated application to open the file."

Comment: I need the excel to open Inside the Application Window

Comment: You can use [tag:poi], for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562214/230513) and [tag:jfreechart], but it's _very_ labor intensive. I don't know an easy solution.