# Processing and displaying large amount of data in Java

Tags: java, excel, javafx, apache-poi, vba

I have a large excel file to process with about 900K records. The requirement is that I have to read the excel file and do some processing on it for e.g. comparing the records for the difference in data and then display the data.

1. I have decided not to user Excel Macros (VBA programming) as I have got to know that macros hang for very large number of records when processing the data.
2. I have thought of using Apache POI to read the Excel file and process the data and then for displaying purpose use Java FX.

My queries:

1. What could be the different approaches for processing large excel file and then displaying the data in table (spreadsheet / excel) format. ?
2. Is my approach of using Apache POI to process the data and Java FX to display the data right? Or there can be better approaches ?
3. Most importantly how do I filter the data based on a column header in Java FX ? This is an important requirement of my project.
4. Also, I have to Bulk update a particular field. For e.g. I have a field as ABC and corresponding to that field I write some data in the next column. Then wherever I have that field in the table the particular value should be copied in the next column.

Please do share your valuable suggestions.

Comment: My suggestion: don't use Excel spreadsheets for representing your datasets.  Use a database or a CSV file.  (Look at all the other questions where people talk about problems with large spreadsheets ....)

Comment: Your question is too broad. A long while back I wrote a proof-of-concept JavaFX table view that had >1,000,000 rows, loading them from a web resource in a background thread (can't find the code now, but it is out there somewhere...); it works fine. Filtering a table view is pretty standard, e.g. http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/ (you can easily put the text field in the column header). Last requirement just sounds like a dependency between properties in the model, which in JavaFX you would handle with properties and/or bindings.

Comment: hi stephen .... how would a CSV file help me ? please could you elaborate more on the same... can I filter a CSV file on the basis of columns ... can I compare 2 CSV rows .... can apache POI read a CSV file with 900K records ....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, but you may get some ideas from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513) that uses a `SwingWorker<TableModel, String>` to read large text files and display them in a `JTable`. The same approach in JavaFX should see similar benefits. The corresponding model in JavaFX might be a `Task<ObservableList<Row>>`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056730/230513) for `Task<Canvas>`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30062075/230513) shows how to traverse the rows and cells in a `Sheet`. You should be able to filter rows as they arrive or later in the `TableView`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17017364/230513). Naturally, you'll need to prototype this and [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to be sure it meets your requirements.

Comment: This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44214756/processing-and-displaying-large-amount-of-data-in-java/44216953?noredirect=1#comment75445615_44214756) makes me think it's worth pursuing. I'm pretty sure `TableView` uses flyweight rendering, as does `JTable`.