# Reading a date value from a cell through XSSF sheet in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting an date in an cell in excel sheet having extension .xls that i am reading through POI in java for HSSF sheet i have the below cross check that is working fine

```
if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(row.getCell(0))) {
}
```

Now please advise i am getting few sheets having extension .xlsx please advise how can i implement the above method to read date value from acell in XSSF sheet

Comment: @trashgod No this is not duplicate of this , well please advise how can i get equivalent method for xssf sheet as I have for hssf sheet

Comment: It is. This helpful [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34108544/230513) summarizes the correct approach, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562214/230513) in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Apache POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html) (who ever heard of reading the docs?), you need to change from `HSSFDateUtil` to [DateUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html)

So your old code

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;

....

if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(row.getCell(0))) {
```

Just becomes

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;

....

if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(row.getCell(0))) {
```

And you're done!

Comment: Exactly; a complete example is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562214/230513).