# Apache poi returning Date cell value as string(integer value)

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read a cell value which holds the date as a value with a custom format. Apache poi is returning me the value as a string(integer number).

DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
return formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

DataFormatter is not working. I am getting same value even

[image]

Comment: "DataFormatter is not working": For me `DataFormatter` works pretty good for each kind of date formatting and especially for the format you are showing. What `apache poi` version are you using? How does it look in Excel? (Screenshot, which shows the cell and the formula bar, please). Best would be a complete minimal reprodicible example. Sample Excel file to download and complete code to test.

Comment: Getting the date value as 44763 for the given date

Comment: For me, using current `apache poi 5.2.2`,  `DataFormatter` works as expected and returns a string in format `dd.MM.yyyy` in that case. As told, [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please.

Comment: I am using an older version 2.28.0, which is returning me the number of days from 01/01/1900. I will update the pom to the latest one and will give it a try.

Comment: Sorry version 4.0.1

Comment: I've been doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562214/230513) for over a decade, currently with `poi-5.2.2`.