# I have an xlxs parser. In the code. I can't change my approach much

Tags: java, spring-boot, parsing, apache-poi

```
      public ResponseEntity<Object> importPcpXlsx(MultipartFile xlsx) {
      try {
        XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsx.getInputStream());
        XSSFSheet xssfSheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        int i = 1;
      
        List<String> number = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
         if (xssfSheet.getRow(i) != null) {
           row = xssfSheet.getRow(i);
           cell = row.getCell(0);
 
           if (cell.getSheet()
              .getRow(0)
              .getCell(0)
              .getRichStringCellValue()
              .getString()
              .equals("Number".trim())) {
            
             number.add(cell.getStringCellValue().trim());
 
             log.info("number: " + i + ".  № " + cell.getStringCellValue());
           }
         } else {
           i = 1;
           break;
         }
         i++;
        }
     
        List<String> kpgz = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
          if (xssfSheet.getRow(i) != null) {
          
            row = xssfSheet.getRow(i);
            cell = row.getCell(1);
 
            if (cell.getSheet()
               .getRow(0)
               .getCell(1)
               .getRichStringCellValue()
               .getString()
               .equals("kpgz".trim())) {
 
             kpgz.add(cell.getStringCellValue().trim());
 
             log.info("kpgz: " + i + ". " + cell.getStringCellValue());
           }
         } else {
           i = 1;
           break;
         }
         i++;
       }
```

I go through the columns and read all the lines under each column. But what if I have some columns will     not come in xlxs file. That is, I need an option where I do not have to strictly specify columns. Please predict. In code Iread by columns, since columns have different types and should be processed differently. I need to do this so that I do not specify the number of columns in the column number code, as I did cell = row.getCell(0); or row.getCell(1) or row.getCell(2)

Comment: Please explain more correct. It is not understandable. You don't know the type of data in the cell, don't you?

Comment: Why not read in row order like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562214/230513)? You can still  `switch` on `getCellType()`.

Comment: Игорь Ходыко, now I'm binding to specific columns. For example getCell(0) and get.cell(1). I don’t understand how to do it so as not to become attached like that

Comment: trashgod, I can't do this, I have to do this in many places(

Comment: @trashgod,  my version is suitable when the columns in the file do not change, but if some columns do not come into xlxs, then the code will not work correctly

Comment: @Игорь Ходыко my version is suitable when the columns in the file do not change, but if some columns do not come into xlxs, then the code will not work correctly

Comment: Try setting https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html when you fetch the cell to control what to do if there's no cell in that column?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am checking xssfSheet.getRow(i).getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL) == null. But but my main goal is not to be attached to cell numbers

Comment: Explain please how is xlxs forming? And what do you do there.  I need a little more context. May be you can make a small example.

Comment: @Игорь Ходыко, xlxs comes to me with already known column names. But there may be such a case that some speakers are missing, and then I have the wrong flash memory. I usually always import and parse xlxs with the same number of columns, but here the number is different

Comment: So, but you can check the columns on runtime and bind its name to your data?

Comment: @ИгорьХодыко 
I need to do something similar - do not specify the number of columns in the column number code, as I did cell = row.getCell(0); or row.getCell(1) or row.getCell(2). But I don't do it in code..

Comment: Do you know maximum size of columns and the number of row where title of columns is?

Comment: @ИгорьХодыко yes(I need just count of colums) int noOfColumns = xssfSheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); , i tried that using

Comment: @ИгорьХодыко I think the approach is a little confused and a little wrong..

Comment: Let's look, as I see you have dynamically changing columns, but you can know about their existence only by cells. Or you need to open more info or it is only the way.

Comment: Maybe you can change behavior of file forming? Why is it dynamical?

Comment: @ИгорьХодыко because another service can send 20 columns, or maybe 10. I just made a binding to the size and increment with checks, but I don’t think this is a good option

Comment: Read the first row, record what column indexes all the column headings that you're interested live in for that file, then when you process the rest of the rows map based on the column index to column heading?

Comment: You get the file or data?

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes thanks, I'm trying to do that. to get a universal version

Comment: @ИгорьХодыко file xlxs

Comment: If you can definetly identify name of column and correlate with data, I don't think it is a huge problem. But if it is not, you should change api from service side, I think.

Comment: Maybe we need change the question a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the columns one by one and bind their type, then check data under these columns.

See example of type checking there:
[Best language to parse extremely large Excel 2007 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560950/best-language-to-parse-extremely-large-excel-2007-files/3562214#3562214)

If you can definetely identify column, it is not a problem. If not, you should think about changing api.

Comment: An example from 2010? - that will not work with latest POI code - latest code has a CellType enum instead of using ints.

Comment: @PJFanning: Thanks! Updated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562214/230513).